# How to prevent sublime text from inserting closing curly braces at wrong location in html templates?

Tags: meteor, formatting, sublimetext3

I'm developing with the Meteor platform and there's this annoying bug that inserts the closing curly brace in the wrong location sometimes. For example:

```
<section>
  {{#if isConditionTrue}}
  {{|
    {{> templateName}}
  }
  }
  {{/if}}
</section>
```

`|` represents the cursor's location.
This happens after typing `{{`

It should actually look like this:

```
<section>
  {{#if isConditionTrue}}
  {{|}}
    {{> templateName}}
  {{/if}}
</section>
```

But because of this: `{{> templateName}}`, sublime text is attempting to completely wrap that child curly brace statement.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

I tried to use a snippet hoping I could override the default behavior, but no luck. I also tried messing around with the key bindings a little bit too, but no luck there either.

**Update**
I just found this in my default sublime keymap file, I'm not really too sure how to modify these without messing up the wrapping for my js files:

```
// Auto-pair curly brackets
    { "keys": ["{"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "{$0}"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|$)", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["{"], "command": "wrap_block", "args": {"begin": "{", "end": "}"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "indented_block", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["{"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "{${0:$SELECTION}}"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
```

**Update #2**
I grabbed the following from the default keybindings file, copied it over to my user key bindings file, and changed `"operand": true` to `"operand": false`, and the seems to be preventing the wrapping.

```
{ "keys": ["{"], "command": "wrap_block", "args": {"begin": "{", "end": "}"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "indented_block", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
    ]
},
```

But it's effecting the auto wrapping of conditionals in my js files. So if I try to wrap and existing conditional that didn't have brackets.

So if I try to wrap this:

```
if (condition)
  console.log('dkslfds');
```

I get this:

```
if (condition) {}
  console.log('dkslfds');
```

Not a huge deal though, and I could live without this if I have to.

**Update #3**
Here's my package control settings file:

```
{
    "bootstrapped": true,
    "in_process_packages":
    [
    ],
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "42 Headers",
        "AAAPackageDev",
        "Abacus",
        "All Autocomplete",
        "Autoprefixer",
        "Babel",
        "Emmet",
        "ES6-Toolkit",
        "Git",
        "GitGutter",
        "Handlebars",
        "HTML5",
        "HTMLAttributes",
        "Jade",
        "JavaScript & NodeJS Snippets",
        "JavaScriptNext - ES6 Syntax",
        "JSCS-Formatter",
        "LESS",
        "One Dark Color Scheme",
        "Package Control",
        "SCSS",
        "SideBarEnhancements",
        "Stino",
        "Stylus",
        "Stylus-Snippets",
        "SublimeLinter",
        "SublimeLinter-jscs",
        "Terminal",
        "Theme - Brogrammer",
        "Theme - Flatland",
        "Theme - Spacegray",
        "TodoReview",
        "WordPress"
    ],
    "repositories":
    [
        "https://github.com/gepd/Stino/tree/new-stino"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any Meteor plugins installed?

Comment: No Meteor plugins @MattDMo

Comment: I can't replicate your problem using Build 3095 on Windows 7 with the standard HTML syntax...

Comment: I'm on build 3083.. I have a feeling something other than the build is causing the problem though.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings-User`, as well as `Preferences -> Settings-User`?

Comment: Sure, just posted under Edit #3 @MattDMo